# Filter on column except when certain condition in a different column

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

I am a little new to Oracle and PeopleSoft but this is my issue.

I need to filter some rows out of a database based on a couple column conditions, but if these conditions meet a different condition in a separate column they should still be included. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM PS_SAA_ACRSE_AVLVW 
WHERE CATALOG_NBR NOT LIKE '%000%' AND CATALOG_NBR NOT LIKE '%900%'
```

This works fine, but if the CATALOG_NBR IS '900' AND SUBJECT column is 'SAA' any of these should be included.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about `OR` ?

```
SELECT * FROM PS_SAA_ACRSE_AVLVW 
WHERE ( CATALOG_NBR NOT LIKE '%000%' AND CATALOG_NBR NOT LIKE '%900%' )
   OR ( CATALOG_NBR = '900' AND SUBJECT_column = 'SAA')
```